# Adding file field to WordPress widget's back-end interface?

Tags: wordpress, file, widget, fieldtype

Is it possible to add file field to WordPress widget? All examples I can find on the Net are creating text input and text area fields. I guess it would work the same way with select, but what about a file?

So, to make it clear - when admin administrates the widget beside text fields I want to allow him to i.e. upload some image.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the function `media_buttons()` inside the Widget `form()` method. That will render a Media Button:

[image: upload button in widgets]

If you need to add the uploaded attachments information into the widget, [follow this lead](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/82874/12615).